# Purpose of a dedicated "Solution Items" project in .sln file

Tags: c#, .net-core, ardalis-cleanarchitecture

I was looking at the `.sln` file generated from the template at https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture, and noticed there is this part:

```
Project("{UUID-1}") = "src", "src", "{UUID-2}"
EndProject
Project("{UUID-1}") = "tests", "tests", "{UUID-3}"
EndProject
...
Project("{UUID-1}") = "Solution Items", "Solution Items", "{UUID-4}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        .editorconfig = .editorconfig
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

What exactly is the purpose of the "Solution Items" project? Does it cause the files listed (e.g. the default `.editorconfig`) to be treated in some special way? Do I need to add any new solution-related file (e.g. `.stylecop.json`) to this list?

Answer (score 3):

> What exactly is the purpose of the "Solution Items" project?

It's not really a project but a pseudo folder in the Solution Explorer. You can create one yourself:

- Right-click the solution, Add, New Solution Folder. Then type a name.

So the purpose is to organize your files and avoid cluttering the Solution Explorer root folder.

Note that it is not a real physical folder, just a pseudo folder in the SE window. You can drag files and folders into it.

You could, for instance, drag Test projects from different sections of your solution together in a Tests folder.

Comment: I sometimes use the "Solution Items" for documentation and readme files.

Answer (score 2):

It gets added when you add a file directly to the solution. This helps to avoid cluttering the root folder of the Solution Explorer and keeps your files well-organized.